# A Probability Question Regarding Dice

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

> Two fair $6$-sided dice are rolled, one red and one blue. Let $A$ be the event that the red die's result is $3$. Let $B$ be the event that the blue die's result is $4$. Let $C$ be the event that the sum of the rolls is $7$. What is the chance of $\Bbb P(A \mid (B \cap C)')$?

I know the answer is $\frac17$. Could someone show me the process of calculation?

​

​

Comment: My standard complaint: "dices" is not a noun! (It can be a verb meaning "cuts into small cubes".)  "Dice" itself is the plural of "die".  You are talking about "throwing dice" not "throwing dices".

Comment: $P(A|(B\cap C))$ means "the probability that the red die comes up 3 [b]given[/b] that the blue die came up 4 and the sum of the dice is 7". Given that the sum is 7 and the blue die was 4, the red die **must** be 7- 4= 3.  That probability is 1, not 1/7!

Comment: What I am asking is P(A∣(B∩C)′), not P(A∣(B∩C)).   ' means complement.

Comment: The condition looks funny $(B\cap C)'=B'\cup C'$... (Given $A$)  If $B'$ it doesn't matter what $C'$ is.  However if $B$, then $C$..  So it seems $P(A|(B\cap C)')=P(A|B')$.

Comment: No. It is not. P(A|B') = 1/6 because B and A are independent. However, (∩)' and A are dependent.

Comment: @NomardicRoku As user247327 has said: $\mathbb P(A|B\cap C)=1$. Therefore $\mathbb P(A|(B\cap C)')=0$, not $\frac17$ again.

Comment: @callculus It is certainly not true that $P(A|E)+P(A|E')=1$ in general, so your comment is mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

There are 36 equally probable outcomes of the pair of dice. Only one of these is in the event $B\cap C$, namely the one where the red die equals 3 and the blue die equals 4. Of the 35 events remaining in $(B\cap C)'$, exactly 5 of them result in the sum of the two dice equaling 7. Therefore $P(A| (B\cap C)') = \frac5{35} = \frac17$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  This one answers my question.

Comment: However, I feel like it should be exactly 5 of them that a = 3 because incident A stands for a = 3.  5 means incident A have 5 samples when (∩)′  happen. 5 should not be '5 of them result in the sum of the two dice equaling 7' because it is not incident A stands for. Even though it is the other 5 samples that a + b =7 in that condition.

Comment: (∩)′  gives us a sample space of 35 incidents, after cutting off the (∩) which stands for the incident a =3 b =4 c =7. (|(∩)′)  means we need to find the probability of a = 3 in the left 35 incidents. So we have a,b,c (3,1,4), (3,2,5), (3,3,6),(3,5,8), (3,6,9), which gives us (|(∩)′) =5/35=1/7.